# python dictionary get by value

Tags: python, dictionary

So my problem is how to get VALUE by key rather getting a pointer. I have the following code, and I want to do sth to tempA without changing the value within dictionary.

```
temp_keys=["a","b","c","d"]
temp_values=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
temp=dict(zip(temp_keys,temp_values))

tempA=temp.get('a',temp.copy())
tempA.append(2)
print temp
```

output is:

```
{'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [4, 4]}
```

See the value of key "a" has been changed.
I want my variable temp unchanged,

```
{'a': [1, 1], 'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [4, 4]}
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output also? Just for the sake of completeness

Comment: done editing, can u help?

Comment: Why not just do anything? Your expected output will work with the first 3 lines you have

Comment: you know copy, so why don't you copy after get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to copy a dictionary value, in this case a list, and the append an element to the copy.

You can use `new_list = list(old_list)` or `new_list = old_list[:]` to copy a list in python.

```
# Our dictionary:
my_dict = {'a': [1, 1], 'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [4, 4]}

# Copy element a:
new_a = list(my_dict['a'])
new_a.append(2)

print my_dict  # {'a': [1, 1], 'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [4, 4]}
print new_a    # [1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for deep copy

```
import copy
temp_keys=["a","b","c","d"]
temp_values=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
temp=dict(zip(temp_keys,temp_values))
print temp
temp_copy = copy.deepcopy(temp)
temp_copy['a'].append(2)
print temp
```

Your `temp` will remain unchanged:

> {'d': [4, 4], 'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'a': [1, 1]} {'d': [4, 4],
>   'b': [2, 2], 'c': [3, 3], 'a': [1, 1]}

Comment: `deepcopy` is not required here as the lists are not nested

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your values are a *list* which is a mutable structure. For this you need to [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy)

```
>>> temp_keys=["a","b","c","d"]
>>> temp_values=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
>>> temp=dict(zip(temp_keys,temp_values))
```

So far so good. Now *copy* the returned value and not the passed argument

```
>>> tempA=copy.copy(temp.get('a',temp))
```

Now the output will be as expected

```
>>> tempA.append(2)
>>> print temp
{'a': [1, 1], 'c': [3, 3], 'b': [2, 2], 'd': [4, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
tempA=temp.get('a',temp.copy())
```

to

```
tempA=temp.get('a').copy()
```

**Explanation**
If you print id of key 'a' of both dictionary (original and copied), you'll find they refer to same location in memory. Thus change in one affects another.

```
newtemp = dict(temp)
print(id(newtemp.get('a')))
print(id(temp.get('a')))
```

output

```
39274840
39274840
```

Comment: Yes this the best answer here +1 to you